# django - data preset in DB, but can't see through Model.objects.all()/Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to save the Profile details for a user, who is already registered with email, phone number etc.

My form submits successfully and redirect to profile page as desired. The profile data is visible in template like `{{request.user.profile.dob}}`

However when I access the /admin page and browse through `/admin/profiles/profile/`, it says `0 profiles`.

When I run Profile.objects.all() through shell, it gives `<QuerySet []>`.

However, when I access the profile through one of the User objects, I get the data. The profile data is present when I check through sqlite console with the query `select * from profiles_profile;`

I'm getting mad, but I think it must be an obvious mistake at my end.

Please help.

Thanks

---

Here's my models

```
/users

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, help_text="A verification link will be sent to this email-id")
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    mobile = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=10,null=True, verbose_name="mobile number",)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

/profiles
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True, related_name="profile")
    name=models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    dob=models.DateField(blank=False,null=True, verbose_name="Date of birth",);
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Here's my ModelForm

```
class PersonalDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=('name', 'dob', )
```

and CreateView

```
class AddPersonalDetails(CreateView, ):
    model=Profile
    form_class=PersonalDetailsForm
    def form_valid(self, form):

        profile = form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = self.request.user
        profile.save()
        return redirect(reverse('my_profile'))
```

Upon submitting the form,

Comment: Remove `primary_key=True` on your `Profile` model. That's wrong. You can't make `user` a pk.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your issue, don't set `null=True` on a `CharField` (`Profile.name` and `User.mobile` in your case), only set `blank=True` if you allow profiles with empty name. See [this explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null) for why.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed `primary_key` from `user` filed. But still, `Profile.objects.all()` returns `<QuerySet []>` after saving profile form for a user.

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate after making this change?

Comment: Yes (migrated Profile model to initial). As it's in dev mode and I'm using sqlite, I've even deleted entire db and recreated it. `u=User.objects.get(id=2)`, `u.profile.id` gives `2`. However, 'p=Profile.objects.get(id=1)', gives `profiles.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist.` :(

Comment: Can't believe, when I migrated to postgre with the same data, everything works as expected. Looks like an sqlite bug. Sigh!